# Why ARMv7-A crashes when flushing the stack pointer from the cache

Tags: c, linux-kernel, arm, cpu-cache

I am trying to evict the memory address in which the stack pointer is pointing to it in an ARM Cortex-A8 processor. I am trying to do that with the below code:

```
cpy r3, sp
mcr p15, 0x0, r3, cr7, cr6, 0x1
```

I have run the above code in a loadable kernel module. after running the above code in the kernel,  OS crashes and needs a restart. but the above instructions work fine for flushing a variable from the cache.

Can anyone give me any advice to solve the problem?

Comment: The stack (sys sp I am guessing) is special in Linux as it has a thread_info which gives the kernel access to process information.   Note: **The minimum time to complete these CP15 and CP14 operations is 60 cycles. However, the timing of these instructions varies highly. It can take hundreds of cycles, depending on the operation and on the current processor activity.**  You don't have any DSB type stuff.  So actual flushing may take place as you try to return from the code.

Comment: Linux is a an *open source* project at least partially to allow people to learn.  You can look at [cache-v7.S](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/cache-v7.S?h=v5.3-rc1#n329) and see there is errata for Cortex-A8 devices as well as much more to it.  Note, there is [an interface](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/cacheflush.h?h=v5.3-rc1) to use these routines.

Comment: The code in cache-v7.S is using to PoU as opposed to PoC (cr7, cr11 vs cr6); so both L1/L2.  I think you can make the L1/L2/memory inconsistent if you don't use the proper instructions (and sequencing).  The L2 has completely different mechanism to flush afair.  I think it is memory mapped I/O.  Things will work 'fine' with a variable as it won't corrupt program execution.  You are making a variation on a 'stack overflow'; corrupting stack via inconsistent cache.  Also you don't take care of branch prediction in your snippet above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to artless noise, actually ARM cortex-a8 has 3 types of command for cache manipulation based on Modified Virtual address:

```
Invalidate (C6, 1) (just invalidate the cache line)
Clean (C10, 1) (Update memory if the cache line is dirty)
Clean & Invalidate (C14, 1) (Update memory then invalidate cache line)
```

and as you can see in the question I used Invalidate instruction and it caused that memory to have invalid data for the stack. but after using Clean&Invalidate instruction the problem was solved. so the final code is as below:

```
cpy r3, sp
mcr p15, 0x0, r3, cr7, cr14, 0x1
DSB SY
```